# Angular Element v/s Customizing the Selector in app.component.ts

Tags: angular, angular-elements

Trying to understand the concept of Angular Element. If I just change the selector defined in the app.component.ts from app-root to hello-world (and combine the generated js files into one), I can use that as a custom tag "hello-world" in my html.

Does the Angular Element give anything more than this? Most tutorials I have seen, have a long sequence of steps to generate an Angular Element. Please help me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it has many components like app.component.html, app.componnet.scss, app.componnet.ts, app.module.ts, app-routing.module.ts.
all of these dependencies cannot be separated